# What's the Eclipse run code shortcut on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I'm running code in eclipse 8 and everytime I have to hit the green button on top. I believe there's a keyboard shortcut with which I can run code easier. But I'm confused about Mac keyboard. Can someone help me out this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Shift + Command (Cmd) + F11

Comment: I don't think it's working @greg-449 I pressed these three together but it just lowers the sound volume since F11 is for lowering sound volume... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I got it! nvm :) @greg-449

Answer (score 1):

You just answered your own question - press at once Shift+Command+F11 and it will run.

If you don't have F11 then you can use F8 - resume Debug - it should work too.

You also can assign any combination of the keys to any function in the prefernces:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Alex! I think I figured it out! :)

Comment: I recently moved from Windows to Mac and I always have the habit of pressing ctrl + f11. But in Mac if you do not press all three buttons together then it will not run your program. So to fix that I went to system preferences, select keyboard and check the "Use the F1, F2 etc. keys" box. That way you can simply press command + f11 to run your eclipse program and you can use fn key + f11 to lower the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is if you have a keyboard with layered functions such as mine where F11 is also the volume down then you also need to hold down the "fn" key.